# What is the best way to change WPF layout when orientation changes?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, layout, storyboard

My UI have to change with the orientation of the screen. Especially i have to change the grid.rows/columns-property and the allignment of my Controls. An animation of the position-change from my Controls would be nice but it doesn't have to.
Much more important for me is that i have an short and clearly arranged code.

I have some approaches but may be there are some more or better ways.

1. I create an extra View for each orientation-state. (This generates double Code - may be not very good, or does it?)
2. Something like Storyboard where i can change the position of controls with XAML. (i don't know how to change grid.row and alignment with storyboard - is it actually possible?)
3. Change it by C#-code. (but I think this is not a proper WPF-style?)

May be with an Example.

Thx Stefan

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use [RotateTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to rotate your view when the orientation changes.

Another approach:
Since you were trying to work with `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` swapping, I'd rather recommend to use `StackPanel`, where you'd just need to set the `Orientation` dependency property to `Horizontal` or `Vertical`.

*Note: You are right, I do not recommend either to use C# code in order to solve this, since it's a situation on the `View` side, not on the `Model` one. (Separation of Concerns.)*

Comment: If you rotate the View, you also have to rotate all Elements of the view back because Windows also rotate the screen. With many Controls on the UI the code will became confusing i think.

To Work with an Stackpanel is an intresting idear and in my case it might work. But i think this is not always an option so there is maybe an other way to do that?